# How to make scrolling up in 2014a Matlab Command Prompt case sensitive?

Tags: matlab

In the Matlab command prompt, "scrolling" up by the arrow up key or mouse scroll with a starting string already entered will roll back to the last commands with the same starting string. I am using R2014a and the roll back is not case-sensitive. How do you make it case-sensitive?

For example, enter

```
>> fun
```

and then click "UP" may give

```
>> Func1
```

and I don't want that.

Comment: In the options/preferences menu, go to Command History, in the second set of options there should be a check box for Match Case (at least, there is in 2015a).

Comment: Thanks. But that option doesnt seem to be under the same tab for 2014a.

Comment: This ought to work then: http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/143448-r2014b-up-arrow-in-command-line-now-ignores-case-never-did-before

Comment: It does work. Thank you!  Want to post a response so that I can close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open the Command History, then click the arrow in the top right of the box, there is an option to toggle Match Case on or off.

In Matlab 2015a and later, there is a new Preferences menu setting. Go to Preferences/Command History, and there is a checkbox for Match Case.